# rails 4 cancancan polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cancancan

For whatever reason code that use to work regarding following/follower no longer works, I suspect I need a cancancan rule, but I am not sure.  Hopefully someone can see my mistake...

Profile model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :follower_relationships, foreign_key: :following_id, class_name: 'Follow', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :follower_relationships, source: :follower
  has_many :following_relationships, foreign_key: :follower_id, class_name: 'Follow', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :following_relationships, source: :following
  ...
end
```

Follow model

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :follower, foreign_key: 'follower_id', class_name: 'Profile'
  belongs_to :following, foreign_key: 'following_id', class_name: 'Profile'
  ...
end
```

Profiles Controller

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  load_and_authorize_resource
  ...
  def follow
    if current_user.profile.follow(@profile.id)
      SystemMailer.following_email(@profile.user, current_user).deliver_later
      redirect_to request.referrer
    end
  end

  def unfollow
    redirect_to request.referrer if current_user.profile.unfollow(@profile.id)
  end
```

current ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  ...
  can :edit, Profile, user_id: user.id
  can :read, Profile
  can :update, Profile, user_id: user.id
  can :show, Profile
  can :manage, Profile, id: user.profile.id
```

I have tried various can abilities, but I feel like I am just hacking around.  If there is no errors with the lines above, can someone point out the can rule that I should put in place?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it's hard to understand, did it work with cancancan before? Or you have just added new functionality?, Cancancan works with users, can you post profile and follows controllers?. Check out https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities

Comment: @Gaston I added the additional points of code as you asked, there is no Follows controller just a model for persisting the changed state.

Comment: What is not working? Is not clear from your question. is not allowing you to call the `follow` method?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it actually wasn't being blocked because of the model organization, the actions were not being permitted in the ability class.

adding:

```
can :follow, Profile
can :unfollow, Profile
```

Solved the issues.  Sorry to waste everyone's time.